# Refresh vars for all projects using a Variable Set in Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

We have a variable set in Octopus which is used by a large number of projects. Among other things, this variable set contains an api key which we need to update.

Since we use a lot of triggered deploy with immutable infrastructure, we have a lot of "redeploys" of an existing project, so we can't simply wait for new releases to update to the new variable values.

Is there any way I can trigger a "variable update" on all "currently deployed" releases in all projects that use a certain variable set? I'm dreading the thought of having to spend hours clicking around in Octopus to get stuff updated, that's nearly an impossible task given our number of projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a script that composes the underlying API requests into one action.

You can find some documentation on the API at https://demo.octopus.com/swaggerui/index.html

The Dashboard endpoint will give you the current release that is deployed in each environment for each project.

It may be easier to keep track of which projects you want to refresh, but you can query the projects endpoint for project details including what variable sets are included.

From there you can use the releases/{id}/snapshot-variables endpoint to refresh the variables for that release.

There are examples of using the API at https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api

Comment: thanks for the help! regarding "The Dashboard endpoint will give you the current release that is deployed in each environment for each project." - I'm not seeing this, and the endpoint isn't documented either. Do you happen to have more info?

Comment: Sure thing, you can see that endpoint here: https://demo.octopus.com/swaggerui/index.html#/Dashboards/CustomActionResponseDescriptor_Octopus_Server_Web_Api_Actions_DashboardViewAction_

If you click "try it out" and then "execute". In the response, look for the Items element and you'll see the list of deployments.

Comment: thanks. The response contains both "Items" and "Projects", I was looking at the wrong one. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help